# Interface NodeMCU (ESP8266) with GSM module

Tags: gsm, esp8266, nodemcu, sim900

I'm a new user of NodeMCU and I would like to make it communicate with a GSM module like SIM900. Can I use the second UART terminal of ESP8266 to interface with the GSM module?

Thanks.

Comment: No, i faced a problem with the uart.alt commands attempt to call field 'alt' (a nil value) !! How can i sove it ?

Comment: resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a tutorial how to do it: http://atcommander.io/Tutorials/Name/ESPInterface

As cagdas said, essentially you use UART0 from ESP8266, remembering to switch its pins assignment to GPIO13/GPIO15 with `uart.alt(1);` in NodeMCU.

To receive debug messages in your computer, you won't be able to use UART0 anymore, but instead you can use UART1 from ESP8266 which is transmit only.

Comment: Seems like the link is down.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The second serial interface has bounded on gpio 13 (rxd2) and 15(txd2). You can switch to control them via these commands on lua:

```
uart.alt(1);
uart.setup(..);
```

So your code gonna be look like :

```
 uart.alt(1) --use alternative gpios
 uart.setup(0, 9600,8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1,0)
 uart.on(...)
 uart.alt(0) --switch back to standard Rx/Tx pins
```

[Here](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/uart/) is the doc for nodemcu uart usage.

If you gonna use arduino, you can use SoftwareSerial library to config any gpio as serial interface like below:

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(16, 5); // RX, TX
mySerial.begin(9600);
```

Comment: I try that but when i put uart.alt(1) i get this error : attempt to call field 'alt' (a nil value) !!

Comment: what is the version of the nodemcu FW you used ? Have you tried to update your nodemcu firmware via [custom build](https://nodemcu-build.com) ?

Comment: I have the 0.9.6 version "noddemcu-floot-0.9.6-dev_20150704.bin" should i update the firmware to get the module support this command ?

Comment: Yes please. Also be sure you have a valid uart define.

Comment: what do you mean by a valid uart define ??

Comment: I mean, be sure you have included the uart module to your custom builds.

Comment: yes, i included the uart module to my custom builds, how many time i will wait to get the firmware in my email, please ?

Comment: just a few seconds. Follow the notifications.

Comment: I have build it 15 minutes ago but i don't recieve any notifications !

Comment: Are you test the communication between nodemcu and a gsm module ??

Comment: it has a common serial interface, tx and rx should work, no need to test.

Comment: OK i wish that, i receive the buid firmware i will try it and i will inform you. Thanks ;)

Comment: I write the code, please check it and i wait for your comments, thanks